# Why isn't parameter useable in a function

Tags: javascript

I realize this might be an elementary school question BUT.

In the following code (not all the code) I'm passing a parameter into the next `then`.

```
.then(cursor => {
  const lastCursorIdx = cursor.length - 1;
  queryAfterCursor = cursor[lastCursorIdx];
  return queryAfterCursor;
})
.then(lastCursorResult => {
  console.log(lastCursorResult);
  const runQuery = lastCursorResult => {
    console.log(lastCursorResult);
  }
  runQuery();
})
```

In the second `then` the parameter is `lastCursorResult`.
When I `console.log` this at the opening of the method.

```
console.log(lastCursorResult);
```

It console logs the details. However when I pass it to the other method `const runQuery` then `lastCursorResult` is u`ndefined`.

I'm wondering why doesn't it work wouldn't I just be able to pass the parameter again and use it?

Comment: Because you've shadowed it by defining a parameter with the same name, then not passed any value for that parameter. *"when I pass it to the other method"* - you **don't** pass it.

Comment: you need to call runQuery with lastCursorResult : runQuery(lastCursorResult) or make runQuery a function without arguments so it will use lastCursorResult in scope

Comment: ^^ e.g., it's a typo (voted to close as such). Either remove the parameter name (`const runQuery = () => { console.log(lastCursorResult); }; `) or pass it into `runQuery` (`runQuery(lastCursorResult);`). I'd go with option A.

Comment: *"However when I pass it to the other method `const runQuery`"* - You're *not* passing it to `runQuery` though... You call it with no arguments: `runQuery();`

Comment: Got it, makes sense.  I knew I'd get downvoted but the curiosity of what I was missing was killing me.

Answer (score 3):

You're shadowing `lastCursorResult` with a parameter. You need to have the function take no arguments:

```
console.log(lastCursorResult);
const runQuery = () => {
    console.log(lastCursorResult);
}

runQuery();
```

Or pass `lastCursorResult` for the argument:

```
console.log(lastCursorResult);
const runQuery = lastCursorResult => {
    console.log(lastCursorResult);
}

runQuery(lastCursorResult);
```